# How to connect custom created events list with calendar view to outlook?

Tags: calendar, outlook

Default sharepoint calendar contains button in ribbon "Connect to outlook".

[image: Default sharepoint calendar view]

I created my custom list based on Event with calendar view and i want to have same funtionallity "Connect to outlook" but its missing!

Content type:

```
<!-- Parent ContentType: Event (0x0102) -->
<ContentType ID="0x0102006fc2817ef05d452b9b857dbd92395114"
             Name="Custom Events"
             Group="Content Types"
             Description="Custom events"
             Inherits="FALSE"
             Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
        <FieldRef ID="" Name="Title"/>
        <FieldRef ID="" Name="Location"/>
        <FieldRef ID=""Name="EventDate"/>
        <FieldRef ID="" Name="EndDate"/>
        <FieldRef ID=""Name="RegistrationDeadline"/>
        <FieldRef ID="" Name="RegistrationUrl"/>
        <FieldRef ID=""Name="Price"/>
        <FieldRef ID=""Name="Comments"/>
        <FieldRef ID=""Name="EventAudience"/>
        <FieldRef ID="" Name="Organizer"/>
        <FieldRef ID=""Name="ContactPerson"/>
        <FieldRef ID="" Name="fAllDayEvent"/>
        <FieldRef ID="" Name="fRecurrence"/>
        <FieldRef ID="" Name="WorkspaceLink"/>
    </FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
```

Ribbons looks like that:

On "calendar" tab button is missing:

[image]

On "list" tab I have button "Connect to outlook" but its disabled:

[image: Custom created list.]

P.s.features "Team Collaboration Lists" and "Group Work Lists"  are activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now i can say that this is not possible. Default template should be modified in code.